# Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is > not allowed in strict mode

Tags: angularjs

I am getting error for following code. Why?

> Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is
>   not allowed in strict mode

```
var _getStudents = function () {

if ($scope.item.ReceivedDate != null) {
    dummyService.getByDate('Students/', $scope.item.ReceivedDate).then(function (response) {
        $scope.Students = response.data;
    }, errorChecker.basic);

}
else {
    dummyService.get('Students/').then(function (response) {
        $scope.Students = response.data;


    }, errorChecker.basic);
}
    $scope.Students = $scope.Students.filter(function (student) { return !student.Removed || student.Id == $scope.itemReport.Count[0].ItemID; });

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemReport.Runs.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < $scope.Students.length; j++) {
            if ($scope.Students[j].Id == $scope.itemReport.Count[i].ItemID) {
                $scope.selectedStudents.selected[i] = $scope.Students[j];
                break;
            }
        } // end inner loop
    } // outer loop

};
```

Error is raised by `errorChecker.basic` of `else` part.

I have used `use strict` at the start of my java script file.